# SpringIntegration and SpringBoot: choose webserver to start by a means other than dependency inclusion/exclusion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, declarative

We have a project in `spring-integration` that will work with either `webflex` or `servlet` implementations and this seems to work pretty well using the `spring.main.web-application-type` property set as a system property.

I'm now looking for how to choose the embedded web server at runtime.

The `spring-boot` documentation says that this is accomplished via dependency inclusion or exclusion with the `pom.xml`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

What I'm looking for is to be able to start any of `jetty`, `netty`, `undertow` or `tomcat` from the same project/executable jar.

Is this feasible by some specific startup sequence in SpringApplication?

Thanks for any pointers/suggestions.

Comment: What is your usecase? It means you would need to include all servers into your app, why would it matter which one starts?

Comment: We want to test the 7 combinations of the different WebApplicationTypes (```servlet```, ```reactive```) with the different embedded servers (```jetty```, ```netty```, ```undertow``` or ```tomcat```).  Do I really have to create 7 different projects for this?  (Note that ```netty``` does not seem to support ```servlet``` hence 7 and not 8 combinations.)

Comment: If this is for testing, execute your tests with different engines as dependencies. Depending on your build system that shouldn't be to hard to do. That being said Jetty and Tomcat don't fully support reactive either, they support reactive types but that is only the async part.

Comment: I want to execute my tests from a single jar, hence my original request and my use case.  Surely this does not require mucking with dependencies.

Comment: A single jar of what? Your tests aren't part of the jar. Just create 6 tasks/profiles in your build and add the dependency you want. That is less of a hassle then trying to add all the dependencies of your jar and build configuration enabling each and every combination, which will impact auto-configuration etc. Your application is still 1 jar, it is just about the tests, configure your build for this.

Comment: In this case, running integration tests by launching the same jar in the N different configurations.  Yes, it's possible to create 7 (or fewer) individual jars from either different profiles or even different projects, but my intention is to have a single jar that is launched in the different configurations in the context of an integration test.  I realize that this is not necessarily easy, hence my request here, but I do not appreciate the attempt to invalidate my use case.

Comment: You don't need 7 jars, that is only your conclusion from my suggestion. I stated you can create 7 tasks (gradle) or profiles (maven) which extend your test configuration to include the configuration (servlet/reactive) and desired server as a dependency. As a result it will all reuse the same generated JAR with your software but run the IT with the desired configuration. I nowhere stated you should create 7 jars/artifacts!

Comment: The integration test environment runs from a JAR and not from MAVEN.  I mentioned above that I'm running from an executable jar. I'll be taking the approach suggested by @artem-bilan.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found a relatively simple and clean way to do this.

At Application context creation, `spring-boot` loads the `WebServerApplicationContext` in one of two flavors, depending upon the value in property `spring.main.web-application-type`: either `reactive` or `servlet` (respectively `ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext` and `ServletWebServerApplicationContext`).

These two classes both have a method `createWebServer()` which will look for a bean of type (respectively) `ReactiveWebServerFactory` or `ServletWebServerFactory` loaded into the context, in which case this bean will be the `WebServerFactory` used by the `WebApplicationContext`.

Hence need to declare the target `WebServerFactory` as a bean.

There are a number of different ways of doing this, including using profiles.

I've chosen to use a factory bean that instantiates the `WebServerFactory` as a function of a system property, here `my.main.web-server` (as a parallel to `spring.main.web-application-type`).

Using a `BeanFactory` to create the bean that holds the `WebServerFactory`:

```java
package net.demo;

...

public class MyWebServerFactoryBeanFactory implements EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment environment;

    public ReactiveWebServerFactory createReactiveWebServerFactory() {
        switch(getWebServer()) {
            case "jetty":
                return new JettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
            case "netty":
                return new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
            case "undertow":
                return new UndertowReactiveWebServerFactory();
            case "tomcat":
            case default:
                return new TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory();
        }
    }

    public ServletWebServerFactory createServletWebServerFactory() {
        switch(getWebServer()) {
            case "jetty":
                return new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
            case "undertow":
                return new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
            case "tomcat":
            case default:
                return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        }
    }

    private String getWebServer() {
        return environment.getProperty("my.main.web-server");
    }
}
```

Using XML context definitions, I define the BeanFactory and import a source which will be different for `reactive` and `servlet`:

```xml
...
<import resource="classpath:my-${spring.main.web-application-type:servlet}.xml" />

<bean id="myWebServerFactoryBeanFactory"
      class="net.demo.MyWebServerFactoryBeanFactory" />
...
```

Finally, create the `WebServerFactory` within the specific source file.  Within `my-reactive.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="myWebServerFactory" factory-bean="net.demo.MyWebServerFactoryBeanFactory"
                              factory-method="createReactiveWebServerFactory" />
```

and within `my-servlet.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="myWebServerFactory" factory-bean="net.demo.MyWebServerFactoryBeanFactory"
                              factory-method="createServletWebServerFactory" />
```

I suppose that you don't necessarily need to have the specialized import because you can create both the `ReactiveWebServerFactory` and the `ServletWebServerFactory` within the context but only the matching bean will be used.

Answer (score 1):

You just can have all of them as a `test` scope dependency and use Spring Boot's `FilteredClassLoader` to exclude whatever you don't need in the current unit test: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration.testing.overriding-classpath.

You might need to learn details of all those auto-configurations for web servers to determine what exactly class to exclude.

Might be also possible to achieve your goal with just plain `@SpringBootApplication.exclude()` (or similar configuration property) for the specific auto-configurations not needed in the current test.

Nothing to do with Spring Integration though.

Comment: I was looking at this possibility, using exclusion.. thanks for confirming that it's feasible.  I agree that it's not specific to Spring Integration and appreciate the help.